# Split array into chunks based on nested data

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I am mapping documents from cloud firestore and trying to put a date header over the first element out of all retrieved documents from firebase which has a specific date.

I was thinking of splitting the retrieved array into chunks based on the date field value and the header would appear only over the first object from the array.

The question is if this is the right way to do it and if yes then how do I exactly execute that. I was trying to Google for hours but I do not seem to get the answer.

This is how I retrieve my data:

```
  function onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Perform lottie animation
    setIsStopped(false);
    setTimeout(() => setIsStopped(true), 400);

    firebase.db
      .collection('time_entries')
      .add({
        description,
        hours,
        minutes,
        createdOn: {
          date: date.toLocaleDateString(),
          time: date.toLocaleTimeString(),
          timestamp: date.toLocaleString()
        }
      })
      .then(() => {
        setDescription('');
        setHours('');
        setMinutes('');
      });
  }
```

This is how I map it inside of the render

```
    {time_entry.map(time_entry => (
      <>
        {loading ? (
          <>
            <FadeIn>
              <Placeholder />
            </FadeIn>
          </>
        ) : (
          <FadeIn>
            <TimeItem
              hours={time_entry.hours}
              minutes={time_entry.minutes}
              description={time_entry.description}
              date={time_entry.createdOn.timestamp}
              doc_id={time_entry.id}
            />
          </FadeIn>
        )}
      </>
    ))}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Pipetus the question is how do I split the array into chunks based on the nested data.

Comment: Can you please give an example of an array you retrieve and the desired outcome? It is a bit unclear.